# What is wrong with this program?

Tags: c, string

I am trying to write a string concatenation code. I wonder what is wrong in it. Can you guyz help me out. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void strcat1(char *s, char *t)
{
    while(*s !='\0')
        s++;

    while((*s++=*t++)!= '\0')
    {

    }

}

int main()
{
char s[]= "hello";
char t[]= "world";
strcat1(s,t);
printf("%s", s);

return 0;
}
```

I am getting this output on codepad.org:  `Disallowed system call: SYS_socketcal`
Here is the link: http://codepad.org/Arz6U7YA

**EDIT**: Will the change char *s = "Hello" and char *t= "World"  in the main function make any differenvce?

Comment: I would put while (s && *s != '\0') myself...

Comment: whats the output in that case?

Comment: Deleted my comment; this program *does* print "helloworld" when I compile it with GCC, but could segfault instead.

Comment: Re EDIT: The change `char *s = "Hello";` will make things worse.  Now you have both an array out-of-bounds problem and a modifying constant data problem.

Comment: oh ya correct. Char *s would save data as literal in data segment. But what the current case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`s` has space for 6 chars (namely 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', and '\0').

You are trying to write there 5 more characters than it can hold.

Don't do that!

Try increasing the size of `s` before

```
int main()
{
char s[11] = "hello";
/* ... */
```

---

Edit after the edit of the OP

Changing `s` in main to

```
char *s = "hello";
```

changes `s` from an array with little space to a pointer to a string literal.

String literals are not modifiable, so you can't expect your code to work with the change.

Comment: how does library strcat work in that case? Does it reallocate memory to the source string and then copy target string?

Comment: No. The pointer can point to a string literal (`s = "hello";` is ok), but the string literal itself cannot be changed (`*s = 'w';` is wrong). Note one expression has the `'*'` and the first doesn't dereference the pointer.

Comment: so could you give me an example of case when I can write *s = 'w' where *s is previously defined?

Comment: thats a pretty good example. So what is best solution for my problem?

Comment: You have a few options: the best varies according to your specific needs. Two options that come to mind now are to copy the standard `strcat` as you did: *then you must ensure the destination has enough space for the resulting string*; or can allocate space for the resulting string and return that (as in `char *strcat2(const char *part1, const char *part2);`)

Comment: But what if I don't want to return a string. The changes should reflect in the source string argument passed?

Comment: You should do like the Standard: in the documentation for your function, specify that accessing beyond the end of objects is undefined behaviour :)

Answer (score 3):

Buffer overflow.  You cannot append to the end of array `s` because it was allocated with only 6 characters (5 printable and one `\0`).

Answer (score 3):

Well, the big problem is that `s` isn't large enough to hold the result; it's sized to hold 6 characters (5 letters plus the 0 terminator), so as soon as you start trying to append the contents of `t`, you overrun the buffer.

Answer (score -3):

You are trying to append to a constant string. That memory segment is protected. Create a new buffer, concat in there, and then return that.

Comment: Incorrect. `s` is an array of char; not a pointer to read-only memory.

Comment: No, he's trying to append to `s`, not the string literal itself.  The problem is that the target buffer is too small for the result.

Comment: wow - C has changed a bit in the 20 years since I've used it. Is that a C99 thing?

Comment: It was like we describe pre-ANSI C89. My version of K&R (version 2) uses the term "string constant" but the behaviour is the same (see page 104).

Comment: @drudru: Nothing's changed, at least not since C89; again, he's not trying to append to the literal, he's trying to append to the auto array that was *initialized* from the literal.

Comment: If you don't want to fix this post, now would be an ideal time to get your very own [peer pressure badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure).